# Split within a Split for direct from MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm using Classic ASP (Yes, I know but I cannot) and MS SQL 2012 as the database and the data type is nvarchar(255) the field name is `"RATE_BREAKDOWN"`

The data is saved from a textarea and it looks like this:

```
Line One = 550.00
Accs = 1000.00
Total = 1550.00
```

Now I would like to loop each line (vbCrLf) and display it in a `<TR>`

for example like this:

```
<tr>
<TD> Line One : </TD>
<TD> $ 550.00 </TD>
</tr>

<tr>
<TD> Accs : </TD>
<TD> $ 1000.00 </TD>
</tr>

<tr>
<TD> Total : </TD>
<TD> $ 1550.00 </TD>
</tr>
```

But how do I do it ?

I tried using a split function to first split the vbCrLf but I have to split within a split (split two times) and I cannot get it to work, plus I think there should be a easier way of doing this.

Here is what I have tried but it's wrong:

```
    <%
    dim tmpValue,strtxtMSG,x,tmpValueB
    strtxtMSG = objRecordSet("RATE_BREAKDOWN")

    tmpValue = Split(strtxtMSG, vbCrLf)
    tmpValueB = Split(tmpValueB, "=")
    %>

            <% for each x in tmpValueB %>
            <tr>
            <TD> <%=tmpValueB(0)%> : </TD>
            <TD> $ <%=tmpValueB(1)%> </TD>
            </tr>
            <% next %>
```

As what the problem has to do with ms sql, I wanted to see if ms sql has an option to loop and split the data and then put that into an array, and not display all of it right away.
something like this `query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE 1=1 AND SPLIT(SPLIT("RATE_BREAKDOWN","NewLine"),"=")"`

The class for the `<TD>` shows up as text ?

```
Response.Write "<tr><td>" & join(split(join(split(objLoad("RATE_BREAKDOWN"), vbCrLf), "</td></tr><tr><TD width='285' class='auto-style57'>"), "=")," : </td><td> $ ") & "</td></tr>"
```

The width='285' class='auto-style57' becomes the text and not part of the page's html/format

Comment: What is `objLoad()`? Is this a recordset? Could you name it better so it's obvious what it is? `obj` is pretty broad. If that's *not* a recordset, I'm not sure exactly what this problem has to do with SQL Server (and it's a stretch even if it is).

Comment: Yes, it's a recordset. I have made the correction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all of the `tmp` variables and going in and out of `<% %>` blocks. Just do this:

```vb
Response.Write "<tr><td>" & join(split(join(split(strtxtMSG, vbCrLf),
  "</td></tr><tr><td>"), "=")," : </td><td> $ ") & "</td></tr>"
```

The reason this breaks when you add additional requirements such as `class='some-thing'` is because now you are splitting by `=` but you also want some `=` to stay. So, you can get around this by replacing those `=` first with something else that won't naturally appear in the data, let's say a pipe `|` character:

```
strtxtMSG = Replace(strtxtMSG, "=", "|")

' then split by | instead of =

Response.Write "<tr><td>" & join(split(join(split(strtxtMSG, vbCrLf),
  "</td></tr><tr><td>"), "|")," : </td><td class='some-thing'> $ ") & "</td></tr>"
```

SQL Server doesn't have any inherent split/join functionality. You could construct a `REPLACE()` command that does this:

```sql
DECLARE @RATE_BREAKDOWN NVARCHAR(255);

SELECT @RATE_BREAKDOWN = N'Line One = 550.00
Accs = 1000.00
Total = 1550.00';

SELECT '<tr><td>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@RATE_BREAKDOWN, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), 
  '</td></tr><tr><td>'), ' = ', ' : </td><td> $ ') + '</td></tr>';
```

And some fancy whiz will probably come along and suggest a `FOR XML PATH` equivalent, probably something better than this:

```
DECLARE @RATE_BREAKDOWN NVARCHAR(255);

SELECT @RATE_BREAKDOWN = N'Line One = 550.00
Accs = 1000.00
Total = 1550.00';

DECLARE @r VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(REPLACE(
  (SELECT @RATE_BREAKDOWN FOR XML PATH('td'),ROOT('tr')),
   ' = ', ' : </td><td> $ '), '&#x0D; ', '</td></tr><tr><td>');

SELECT @r;
```

But both of these are grossly inefficient to perform in T-SQL, and much better handled in the presentation tier. Why should SQL Server know or care about HTML elements like `<tr>` or `<td>`? Just because you *can* do it doesn't mean you *should*.

Even better, by building a better database schema - if these are separate pieces of data, why are they being munged together in a single column?

Comment: Just one problem I'm trying to add a class to the TD and it's always showing as text, how do I fix this ??? I added the code at the end of my question if you can please look at it. Thanks

Comment: @msvuze instead of `width=""285"" class=""auto-style57""` try surrounding those with single quotes, e.g. `width='285' class='auto-style57'`. This may violate some prickly standard somewhere but should be fine for your needs.

Comment: Still getting an error or the text inside the page even if I only try class='auto-style57' ....  :( any other ideas ? Thanks again

Comment: I updated the question it shows no error but the text is inside the page and not in the html ?

Comment: I just noticed one thing it will work on the first one e.g. Response.Write "<tr><TD width=285 class='auto-style57'>" & join(split(....  but it will not work on the 2nd one it will always show it as text!?

Comment: Is there anyway I can separate asp from html like I hoped originally ?

Comment: @msvuze Why would you want to separate asp from html? The problem is that you are trying to embed `=` in your string while also trying to ignore other `=` in the same string. See my update please.